# How to save, HTML5, Latitude and Longitude into database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I need to save the latitude and longitude into my database. I can get the coordinates values but i cannot assign them to the PHP variables so that i could insert them into the database. I have watched a lot of youtube videos and read so many blogs but nun of them worked. I don't know which way is better for inserting coordinates into database, guide me please Thank you.

Following is my code:

```
<body>
    <p>HTML5 GEOLOCATION</p>

    <a href="#" id="get_location">Get Location</a>
    <div id="map">
    <iframe id="google_map" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=9&center=24.8615,67.0099&key=AIzaSyAgiV9XkktBAHcfc1XIkLcUngBuSnxmk1o"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>

        var c = function(pos){
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
                long = pos.coords.longitude,
                coords = lat +', '+long;

            document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src','https://maps.google.co.uk/?q='+ coords +'&z=15&output=embed');
            alert("latitude= "+lat+"\nlongitude= "+long);

        }//end of function c
        document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function(){

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c);
            return false;
        }//end of document.getElementById()
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: ok. how can i use ajax? have any tutorial link?

Comment: I Just post the answer refer this

Comment: solved your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make the ajax call using jQuery to your server side language i.e. PHP and pass lat & lang parameter to your PHP page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your_server_url.php', 
    async:true,
    data: { 
        'lat': lat, 
        'lang': lang 
    },
    success: function(response){
       // alert('wow' + msg);
    }
});
```

In your php page read parameter Like this.

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lang = $_POST['lang'];
//your database logic
```

Comment: please provide comment if downvoted.

Comment: thanks but didn't work bro. this site has restrictions i cannot ask every type of question here can we chat through email?
danijami45@aol.com

Comment: mail me your question at amoltate@yopmail.com

Comment: i am really sorry for late. I have sent you an email on your email address please checkout.

Comment: please sir take a look at your email address, i have sent you an email.

Comment: Hey dude I just help you out. I cant make whole code.

Comment: yeah u are right. thanks for every thing. :)